Light Client (Smoldot) Connecting But Unable To Send Transactions
Implementing smoldot (substrate-connect) on a fork of the polkadot-JS. Connecting to a light node boot node works most of the time, but is intermittent.

When we are able to connect via light client, we can navigate through the entire website very well BUT we cannot send transactions of any kind. Each time a transaction is sent, we get either the infinite blue spinning circle and no result OR (one time only) we got a Dropped error.

We noticed a number of drops and reconnects in the web socket. We see these when connected to a normal RPC node as well so that is not unique to the light client.
What are we missing?
The chain spec header is:
    {
  "name": "Geode",
  "id": "geode_mainnet",
  "chainType": "Live",
  "bootNodes": [
    "/ip4/167.86.91.139/tcp/30336/ws/p2p/12D3KooWE6KQEVWgzzJvecLzAdzEyAozKb1wNhY61nCNxHociEQb",
    "/ip4/167.86.91.139/tcp/30334/ws/p2p/12D3KooWCTdxBFVwMs8yrm63SEJMcWWfGDdGvR4NWyhfMVyyQyBu",
    "/ip4/207.244.232.237/tcp/30334/ws/p2p/12D3KooWS6Zw8jy5yu5a2ShWBYk5E41GZ6wMVDyEBeCjBwGm2hUi",
    "/ip4/207.244.232.237/tcp/30336/ws/p2p/12D3KooWKmnUoPDwD9PDsZ4V9inUH7tE3XrGnHHbVJaXucCziY5T"
  ],
  "telemetryEndpoints": null,
  "protocolId": "geode",
  "properties": {
    "tokenSymbol": "GEODE"
  },
  "forkBlocks": null,
  "badBlocks": null,
  "lightSyncState": null,
  "codeSubstitutes": {},
  "genesis": {...

WSS and Certificates Setup:
The second boot node ("/ip4/167.86.91.139/tcp/30334/ws/p2p/12D3KooWCTdxBFVwMs8yrm63SEJMcWWfGDdGvR4NWyhfMVyyQyBu")as an example, has these flags to set the listen addresses.
  --chain ./GeodeSpec20230211RAW.json \
  --listen-addr=/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/30333 \
  --listen-addr=/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/30334/ws \

And the following WSS/Certificates setup:
server {
  server_name getgeode.com www.getgeode.com;

  location / {
    proxy_buffers 16 4k;
    proxy_buffer_size 2k;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:30334;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
   }
}

I have verified that all relevant ports are allowed in the firewall (UFW).

Can you please share more information about how you connect to the light client? What chainspec you are using? what is the WSS and certificates set up for the bootnodes etc etc?

Thank you! I have added details on the chain spec, WSS/certificates setup on the boot nodes etc to the original question. I would love to know your thoughts!

I am wondering if the problem is in the chain spec where "lightSyncState": null. What are the options there other than null?

Can you provide the full chainspec? And/or a complete repro environment?
If the light client sync state is null it means it will resync from the start of the chain. since you're running a private chain this shouldnt be much of an issuing b/c there shouldn't be a lot of blocks.

There are over 7 Million blocks so far

What are the options for LightSyncState other than Null?

Something like this
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-connect/blob/main/packages/connect-known-chains/specs/polkadot.json#L44
